# Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install Error in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I tried to run my app i am getting the error as CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod
install. When i run the app in the terminal using 'flutter run' it's working perfectly. I don't know why it's not working in Android studio.

Please find the error below.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Flutter doctor also i don't find any issue.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.0.4 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.0/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 85684f9300 (2 weeks ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
    • Dart version 2.17.5
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 0C7D4F63-17B1-4E66-8277-767ED0672937 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5
      (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
    ! Error: iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected. (code -13)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try:
flutter clean &&
cd ios &&
pod update &&
pod install &&
flutter run

Sometimes i got pod error on ios and i had to install and update them manually BCS flutter did not this for me

Comment: i dont find any issue in running the app using the command flutter run. When i try to run the app in the Android studio i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1: Open VsCode terminal or Android Studio terminal. 
STEP 2: sudo gem install cocoapods 
STEP 3: flutter clean 
STEP 4: flutter run